# SQL Server select ONLY columns with permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

Let's say that I have `TableA` that has 5 columns:

```
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5
```

and I am connected to SQL Server via User1. This User1 has permissions to select col1, col2, col3 only

I can do this

```
select * 
from information_schema.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
```

and loop for all return columns and build my select statement, but I have more than 500 select statements in my project (BIG HR Management System), so I need another way with less code modification.

Now if I try

```
Select * from TableA
```

it will return an error.

So how can I select only those columns with permissions without change all my code?

Edited: I want a method to override SQL exception when selecting a column with no permission, just return null and show no exception

Edited 2:- the select * was just an example, to be more simple :
if I have 2 SQL Server users, the first one has permission in col1 - col3
The second one has permission to col4-col6
what is the best method to select columns with permission to every user

Comment: Fix your application so it retrieves only the columns needed.  You may need to construct the queries based on what users have access to.

Comment: You should always select only the columns you need rather than using `*` so I don't see the problem.

Comment: This project is about 10 years old of development, it will take me a month to fix all queries

Comment: Don't you have to change all the queries anyway, even with the hypothetical approach you're asking about? Seems like if you're going to have to rewrite a bunch of stuff anyway, you might as well put that effort into doing it the right way rather than going further down the wrong  path.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly agree with the comments suggesting that different queries be written for different behaviors, rather than doing this dynamically for each user. While I understand the desire to do it dynamically (and you certainly can), it's probably going to be of equal effort, or more to alter all your existing queries to work dynamically.

By the way, you said queries instead of procedures. No clue if that's actually what you're doing, but if your app just constructs ad hoc sql, I'd  recommend using stored procedures instead. If you already are, ignore this last comment.

That said, here is a bit of code which illustrates how you could do this dynamically. Whether you write this code in each of your procedures, or build a function which returns a string (representing the columns the user is entitled to), or build this behavior into a separate stored procedure which gets called by each proc, hopefully this should point you towards your solution.

I built a little mock setup here so this should be fully re-runnable. I just picked one of the existing service accounts (NT Service\SQLWriter) as an arbitrary user for illustrative purposes.

```
-- Assumes you have a dB called test
use test
go

-- Set up test table
if object_id('test.dbo.colpriv', 'U') is not null drop table test.dbo.colpriv
create table dbo.colpriv
(
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int,
    Col3 int
)
insert into dbo.colpriv values (1, 3, 5)

grant select on dbo.colpriv  (Col1, Col3) to [NT SERVICE\SQLWriter]

go

declare 
    @Principal varchar(100) = 'NT SERVICE\SQLWriter', -- Just picked one out of a hat from sys.server_principials
    @Sql nvarchar(max),
    @Columns nvarchar(max)

select 
    @Columns = stuff((select ',' + quotename(column_name)
                      from test.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
                      where table_name = 'colpriv'
                           and grantee = @Principal
                      order by column_name
                      for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),
    @Sql = '
        select ' + @Columns + '
        from dbo.colpriv'

exec sp_executesql @Sql
```